# Show that $v \cdot w = 0$ under specific conditions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be a symmetrix $n \times n$ matrix. (Remember that means $S^t = S$). Let $v$, $w$ be eigenvectors of $S$ for eigenvalues $\lambda$, $\mu$ respectively. Suppose $\lambda \not=  \mu$. Show that $v \cdot w = 0$.

Hints give:

- In other words, the eigenspaces of symmetric matrices are perpendicular to each other.
- Use a: Where you let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Verify that $(Sx) \cdot y = x \cdot (Sy)$. Answer: I verified that they do equal.

Comment: A better title would be the first item after "In other words".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question has been tagged *homework*, read the spoiler below only after you've tried to solve it on your own:

> $ \lambda (v\cdot w) = \lambda v \cdot w =Sv\cdot w = v\cdot Sw = v \cdot \mu w = \mu (v\cdot w)$ implies $(\lambda-\mu) (v\cdot w) = 0$.